# How do I catch error when creating a ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im trying to create an ObjectId with mongoose in my node.js app from the parameters in the route.

If I got this route:

```
/product/:id
```

and I try to create my ObjectId for quering the product collection I use this

```
var o_id = moongose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
```

But if the :id part of the route is NOT an ObjectId string, just some random text I get an error:

```
"Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"
```

How do I catch this error?
I have tried to surround o_id = moongose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) with try{}catch(error) {} but I get nothing in the catch expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940660/whats-mongoose-error-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-xxx-at-path-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a regex to test your expression:

```
if(/[a-f0-9]{24}/.test(req.params.id)) {
   var o_id = moongose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
}
```