# mongoose findbyId internal server error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, koa2

I have a collection of users:

```
db.users.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d9f3435ce78127510332ea"), "index" : 1, "isActive" : false, "name" : "Noble", "surname" : "Downs", "email" : "nobledowns@conferia.com", "phone" : "+1 (812) 412-3775", "address" : "357 River Street, Chelsea, District Of Columbia, 5938" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d9f3435ce78127510332eb"), "index" : 0, "isActive" : false, "name" : "Moore", "surname" : "Vinson", "email" : "moorevinson@conferia.com", "phone" : "+1 (902) 511-2314", "address" : "433 Sullivan Street, Twilight, Maine, 4931" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d9f3435ce78127510332ec"), "index" : 4, "isActive" : false, "name" : "Madge", "surname" : "Garza", "email" : "madgegarza@conferia.com", "phone" : "+1 (828) 425-3938", "address" : "256 Bowery Street, Chesapeake, Wyoming, 1688" }
{ "_id" : "56bc57c4ea0ba50642eb0418", "index" : 10, "isActive" : true, "name" : "Maritza", "surname" : "Foster", "email" : "maritzafoster@conferia.com", "phone" : "+1 (884) 416-2351", "address" : "556 Conway Street, Ernstville, Pennsylvania, 134" }
```

Please note that the last one does not have Object_id, just for my tests.
I'm using Koa2 and using async /await though I think it doesn't affect.
My route is mounted on **/api/users** and is like this:

```
import User from '../models/user'
var router = require('koa-router')();
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 

router
  .get('/', async ctx => ctx.body = await User.find({}))
  .get('/:id', 
    async (ctx) => {
    try {
      let id = ObjectId(ctx.params.id); 
      const user = await User.findById(id)
      if (!user) {
        ctx.throw(404)
      }
      ctx.body = user
    } catch (err) {
      if (err === 404 || err.name === 'CastError') {
        ctx.throw(404)
      }
      ctx.throw(500)
    }
  })
```

When I load http://localhost:3000/api/users all my users are shown.

When I load http://localhost:3000/api/users/56d9f3435ce78127510332ea only that user is shown.

However.... when I load http://localhost:3000/api/users/56bc57c4ea0ba50642eb0418 I got Internal Server error.

If I load http://localhost:3000/api/users/whatever I also get Internal Server Error

So my questions:
findById is always expecting an Object_id? If this Object_id is no longer in the collections shouldn't it return 404?

What happens if I import my data with my own id? Can't I use findById method? Even if I commented this line? `let id = ObjectId(ctx.params.id);`

Shouldn't a I get a 404 error?

If I change ctx.throw (500) for ctx.body = err I always get {} in the browser. Maybe that's the reason, the err is empty. But why?

Comment: Here's an answer to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25798043/8751225

Answer (score 0):

`if (!user) {
    ctx.throw(404)
}`

will throw an exception and it will be caught by your try/catch statement:

`} catch (err) {
    if (err === 404 || err.name === 'CastError') {
        ctx.throw(404)
    }
    ctx.throw(500)
}`

but err != 404 so it will skip the if statement in try/catch and instead do ctx.throw(500)

to fix it you can do following:

`} catch (err) {
    if (err.message === 'Not Found' || err.name === 'CastError') {
        ctx.throw(404)
    }
    ctx.throw(500)
}`