# Cast to ObjectId failed for value " " at path "_id" for model

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having an error that I do not understand how it happens. If I have my routes in the following order:
[image]

My controller obter_todos_precos is just a console.log and is not using any Model, but i am getting the following error:

```
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"preco\" at path \"_id\" for 
model \"ZonaModel\""
```

I have found a solution by changing the order of the routes in this way:
[image]

Why I am having this behavior?

Comment: Probably the text `preco` was interpreted as an id for the route `:id_zona`

Comment: Try changing `(':id_zona')` to `(':id_zona([1-9]\\d*)')`

Comment: The missing ; after is not the problem.

Comment: Prefer to copy and paste the code instead of a printscreen

Comment: Changing the id_zona with (':id_zona([1-9]\\d*)') works, but my id is a ObjectId so it's not numerical.

Comment: Then we just need a proper regex. Can you describe how your `ObjectId` looks like, so we can match only it?

Comment: The regular MongoDb ObjectId

Comment: Here is your answer: _https://stackoverflow.com/a/14942113/6188402_

Comment: It will look as this `(':id_zona(^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$)')`

Comment: Yes, I found it already. thanks. but what I do not understand is why a path is interpreted as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router matches the first route it match 
/:id_zona and /preco route to the same path as `preco` can also be a value for `id_zona`

so when /preco is above it works,
whereas when /:id_zona is above and you trying to use /preco the the route matches to /:id_zona  and the value of id_zona is preco which in you controller wished to be of ObjectId type

Comment: Using a regex expression when it´s an Id works, but is there a better way to avoid this instead of using regex, or changing the order of my routes?

Comment: changing the order of routes would be better