# Express Server routing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to add a new route to fetch a user by id but my error handling is not working correctly. Here is the code for that route.

```
const express = require('express');

require('./db/mongoose');
const User = require('./models/user');
const Task = require('./models/task');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());

//  ***removed code for brevity
// Route for fetching user by id

app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.params.id);
    const _id = req.params.id;

    User.findById(_id)
        .then(user => {
            //console.log(user)
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(404).send();
            }
            res.send(user);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            res.status(500).send();
        });
});
```

So if I test the route on Postman and I enter the correct user id from the database I get that user sent back, which is the the correct response.  But if I enter an incorrect user id I get the 500 error code response instead of the 404 error code.  The if (!user) statement is getting skipped and I can't figure out why.  Any thoughts as to what I am missing?

Comment: this means you have an error in `User.findById` your catching its error and sending 500 status .. could you post the code and how it's exported? also you could `console.log(e)` in `catch(e)` block and you will see what is the error thrown

Comment: So this is the entire User file I am requiring

Comment: ```const User = new mongoose.model('User', {
 name: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  trim: true
 },
 email: {
  type: String,
  require: true,
  trim: true,
  lowercase: true,

  validate(value) {
   if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
    throw new Error('Email is invalid');
   }
  }
 },
 password: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  trim: true,
  minlength: 7,
 validate(value) {
   let pwd = value.toLowerCase().includes('password');
   if (pwd) {
    console.log("Your password can't contain the word password.");
   }
  }
  // if include password
 },```

Comment: Not sure why it looks like that sorry.  But I am exporting it by calling module.exports = User

Comment: If you would log `e` instead of just ignoring it, you would probably know the error.

Comment: and when I console .log(e) i get this error message:      'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5c8e62681df87697a8dbc2f" at path "_id" for model "User"', along with a lot of other information I can post if you'd like.

Comment: check this answer refering to you received error which is a mongoose  err https://stackoverflow.com/a/14942113/1283672

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this thru my own personal mongoose/express-using project, I get the following error:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "12345" at path "_id" for model "User"
```

That basically means Mongoose is expecting its own specific object type, an "ObjectId". This is a bit of a pain, since normally if you're using .findOne({_id:something), you can just use a string. If we do:

```
User.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id))
```

it should work. Note that if you use an invalid id (like I obviously did here, it'll *still* error out. For that reason, I'd use the standard NodeJS format for callbacky stuff:

```
.then((err,result)=>{
   //other stuff
});
```

In general, the .catch() block should only happen if obviously Mongoose *and* your router can't handle it.

EDIT: Also, for others info, Mongoose.model.findById is a built-in convenience method, and should basically do exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.