# Mongoose find with or operator failing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an input with autocomplete and I want to find user by `_id`, `name` or `email`.

This query is working fine but it search just using name or email:

```
  var matchRegexp = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(req.query.match), 'i');

  User.find(
    {$or: [{email: matchRegexp}, {name: matchRegexp}]},
    {email: 1, name: 1, _id: 0}
    ).limit(limitResults).exec(
    function(error, users) {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          "message": "Query failed",
        });
      } else {
        return res.json({
          "results": users
        });
      }
    }
  );
```

If I try to add `_id` at the `$or` it fails searching by `name` or `email` but it works with `_id`:

```
{$or: [{email: matchRegexp}, {name: matchRegexp}, {_id: req.query.match}]}
```

How can I let it work using all 3 options?

EDIT:

This is the error:

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ayeye" at path "_id" for
>   model "User"

it is not considering at all name and email...

Comment: For me its working. Could you show some documents where the condition is failing

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Thanks for debugging... to me it fire that error I just posted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25798043/6322587 should be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your match string is not a valid `ObjectId` you are getting this error.

So here you can first check the validation for valid `ObjectId` and then make a criteria accordingly.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId

const criteria = { $or: [{ email: matchRegexp },{ name: matchRegexp }] }

If (ObjectId.isValid(matchRegexp)) {
  criteria.$or.push({ _id: matchRegexp })
}

User.find(criteria, { email: 1, name: 1, _id: 0 }).limit(limitResults).exec()
```