# I have the same logic for two routes in this code , but they behave differently

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, passport.js

```
// @route   GET api/profile/handle/:handle
// @desc    Get profile by handle
// @access  Public

router.get('/handle/:handle', (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};

    Profile.findOne({ handle: req.params.handle })
        .populate('user', ['name', 'avatar'])
        .then(profile => {
            //console.log('profile1 ' + profile);
            if (!profile) {
                errors.noprofile = 'There is no profile for this user for handle route (from then block)';
                res.status(404).json(errors);
            }
            res.json(profile);
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ profile: 'There is no profile for this user for handle route (from error block)' }));

});

// @route   GET api/profile/user/:user_id
// @desc    Get profile by user ID
// @access  Public

router.get('/user/:user_id', (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};

    Profile.findOne({ user: req.params.user_id })
        .populate('user', ['name', 'avatar'])
        .then(profile => {
            // console.log('profile not found by userid');
            //console.log('profile2 ' + profile);
            if (!profile) {
                errors.noprofile = 'There is no profile for this user for user_id route (from then block)';
                res.status(404).json(errors);
            }
            res.json(profile);
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ profile: 'There is no profile for this user for user_id route (from error block)',
err: err }));
});
```

I have these two routes as above. First one is to search an user from dB using the handle(username) and the second one is to search using the user_id created by dB itself. When I am requesting to the 1st route using a wrong handle , the then() block gets executed and i got this response:

```
{
    "noprofile": "There is no profile for this user for handle route (from then block)"
}
```

But in the second route (searching by user_id), when i am putting an wrong user_id, the catch block gets executed and i got this response:

```
{
    "profile": "There is no profile for this user for user_id route (from error block)",
    "err": {
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"5cb0ec06d1d6f93c20874427rhdh\" at path \"user\" for model \"profile\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "stringValue": "\"5cb0ec06d1d6f93c20874427rhdh\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": "5cb0ec06d1d6f93c20874427rhdh",
        "path": "user"
    }
}
```

The logic is same for both the routes ,but they are responding differently.What is the reason behind this???

if u want to have a look on Profile schema, here it is:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    handle: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 40
    },
    company: {
        type: String
    },
   ....
....
.....
});
```

I got a warning too while requesting with a wrong handle as below:

```
(node:16996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (H:\MERN Stack Course\devConnector\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (H:\MERN Stack Course\devConnector\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (H:\MERN Stack Course\devConnector\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at Profile.findOne.populate.then.catch.err (H:\MERN Stack Course\devConnector\routes\api\profile.js:75:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:16996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16996) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the error message

```
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"5cb0ec06d1d6f93c20874427rhdh\" at path \"user\" for model \"profile\""
```

`user` field is of mongodb type `ObjectId` and you're providing `String` while `handle` is of type `String`

In case of `handle` query there was no error, only there was no entry in your `db`.

You can fix it like `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.user_id)`. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function)

Also, there's problem with your code. (Execution doesn't stop where you think it stops and you get unhandled promise rejection)

```
.then(profile => {
  //console.log('profile1 ' + profile);
  if (!profile) { // <--- if true
    errors.noprofile = 'There is no profile for this user for handle route (from then block)';
    res.status(404).json(errors); // <-- executes
  }
  res.json(profile); // <--- always executes within then callback
})
```

If this check `if (!profile)` evaluates to `true` then `res.status(404).json(errors)` is executed. And then next `res.json(profile)` is executed.

In your code `res.json(profile)` is always executed when there's no error. You could rectify by either using `return` to stop execution or `if..else` like:

```
return res.status(404).json(errors);

// or
if (!profile) {
  errors.noprofile = 'There is no profile for this user for handle route (from then block)';
  res.status(404).json(errors);
} else {
  res.json(profile);
}
```

Comment: Update answer, check out

Answer (score -1):

I think in your second route you're trying to query with an invalid ObjectID.

Pls check: [What's Mongoose error Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path "_id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940660/whats-mongoose-error-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-xxx-at-path-id)

Comment: yes, that's what my question is, i am knowingly request with a wrong user_id. The issue is when I request with a wrong handle, it executes the then() block, but in case of the second route ,when I request with a wrong user_id , it executes the catch() block.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I know it's intentionally wrong. But the type of it is invalid. That's why you get CastError.
Please check this: 
    const valid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.user_id);

Comment: But I am not interested in what type of error it's coming,I want to know why it is not throwing any error in the 1st route, both have the same logic. And i had tested this with wrong number and string types of user_id , it's saying the same cast error.