# Error Code ' Cast to ObjectId failed for value "find" at path "_id" for model "user" '

Tags: javascript, mongoose, axios, vuex

I try to request user data with req.query but I have trouble like my title question. previously I try with other models and it worked.

controller.js (server side)

```
static getUserByQuery(req, res, next) {
  User
    .find(req.query)
    .then(user => {
      res.status(200).json(user);
    })
    .catch(next);
};
```

my vuex on actions state (client side)

```
getUserByQuery(context, email) {
  Axios
    .get(`${baseUrl}/user/find?email=${email}`)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      context.commit('GET_USER_BY_QUERY', data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
},
```

I use email for sample query, and I hope can be used with other queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's Mongoose error Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path "\_id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940660/whats-mongoose-error-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-xxx-at-path-id)

Comment: Can you show your routes?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Can you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query))` before you do the `User.find()` call?

Comment: this my route - `route.get('/user/find', controllerUser.getUserByQuery);`

Comment: @Phil the error is the same

Comment: What about the console log though? What exactly does the request query look like?

Comment: on product model, I use the same code to get data with the query and its work

Comment: my controller 
`static getProductByQuery(req, res, next) {
    Product
      .find( req.query )
      .then(product => {
        res.status(200).json(product);
      })
      .catch(next);
  };`

Comment: that code already test by postman and I got all the data according to the category