# How can I cast ObjectId in Mongodb? I have tried different ways but still getting errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

## The Schema

//SCHEMA SETUP

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String
})

var campground = mongoose.model("campground", campgroundSchema)


#The error is where coming from here, don't seem to get the campgrounds diplayed
app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function(req, res){
    //find the campground with provided ID
    campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCampground){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            //render show template
            res.render("show", {campground: foundCampground})
        }
    })
})
```

## Error message

** message:
'Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5e61150b58e80830240ef790" at path "_id" for model "campground"',
name: 'CastError',
model: Model { campground } }**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's Mongoose error Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path "\_id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940660/whats-mongoose-error-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-xxx-at-path-id)

Comment: The above listed Url can help you !! I can see there is space in your string   `" 5e61150b58e80830240ef790"` seems like that can be the issue, So trim it & send it, you should be good to go..

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `{ _id: false }` when you create a schema like this

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String
}, { _id: false })
```

Comment: Modie I tried that and I am getting the following error  ~ | <h1><%= campground.name %></h1>
    2|
    3|
    4|

Cannot read property 'name' of null

Comment: that must be something else in your template. I guess it fixed your original problem. Looks like either foundCampground is coming as empty or not propely being passed.

Comment: Why do you've to change something in schema for reads ? Also `{ _id: false }` helps you to avoid auto creation of `_id` but not related to casting errors !!

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your string to MongoId by using the `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` method and pass the your string as the first parameter.

For example after using the above method your code looks something like below

```
app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function(req, res){
    //find the campground with provided ID
    campground.findById(
      mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
      function(err, foundCampground){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            //render show template
            res.render("show", {campground: foundCampground})
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried that and got this error - Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Comment: You need not to convert string to `ObjectId()` using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` as `.findById()` takes in string & converts it internally !!

Comment: Ohkay, then @JamoniJamo must me passing wrong string to the `findById()` method. @JamoniJamo did you tried to log the string before calling `findById()` method.