# get data from mongodb through node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  name: String,
  isbn: String,
  image: String,
})

var PostMessage = mongoose.model('PostMessage', postSchema);


const getBook = async (req, res) => { 
  const { id } = req.params;

  try {
      const post = await PostMessage.findById(id);
      
      res.status(200).json(post);
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
}
```

i want to get data from my mongodb through "id" . if my id matches the value of id in mongodb it gets that object,but its throwing error:

{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "s-CoAhDKd" at path "_id" for model "PostMessage""}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { id } = req.params;

try {
    const post = await PostMessage.findById({id: id});
    res.status(200).json(post);
} catch (error) {
  res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
}
```

Try the above

Answer (score 1):

Based on this thread : [What's Mongoose error Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path "_id"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940660/whats-mongoose-error-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-xxx-at-path-id)

You have to check if your ID meets the requirements of Mongoose ObjectId structure with :

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('your id here');
```

In the docs : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids, it indicates that ObjectIDs are 24 characters hash.
So "s-CoAhDKd" is not a correct format ;)