# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "User"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, express, mongoose

Whenever I login to my app this is what it says, and my user profile does not get my details.
I rechecked everything but cant seem to find the problem.
I am still learning MERN and I am stuck here for a few days.

[image: This is the error i'm getting]

This is my User Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    passwordHash: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    street: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    apartment: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    zip :{
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }

});

userSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

userSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
});

exports.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
exports.userSchema = userSchema;
```

This is my api for the user:

```
const {User} = require('../models/user');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

router.get(`/`, async (req, res) =>{
    const userList = await User.find().select('-passwordHash');

    if(!userList) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(userList);
})

router.get('/:id', async(req,res)=>{
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).select('-passwordHash');

    if(!user) {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'The user with the given ID was not found.'})
    } 
    res.status(200).send(user);
})

router.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    let user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        passwordHash: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
        phone: req.body.phone,
        isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin,
        street: req.body.street,
        apartment: req.body.apartment,
        zip: req.body.zip,
        city: req.body.city,
        country: req.body.country,
    })
    user = await user.save();

    if(!user)
    return res.status(400).send('the user cannot be created!')

    res.send(user);
})

router.put('/:id',async (req, res)=> {

    const userExist = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    let newPassword
    if(req.body.password) {
        newPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10)
    } else {
        newPassword = userExist.passwordHash;
    }

    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            passwordHash: newPassword,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin,
            street: req.body.street,
            apartment: req.body.apartment,
            zip: req.body.zip,
            city: req.body.city,
            country: req.body.country,
        },
        { new: true}
    )

    if(!user)
    return res.status(400).send('the user cannot be created!')

    res.send(user);
})

router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    const secret = process.env.secret;
    if(!user) {
        return res.status(400).send('The user not found');
    }

    if(user && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.passwordHash)) {
        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                userId: user.id,
                isAdmin: user.isAdmin
            },
            secret,
            {expiresIn : '1d'}
        )
       
        res.status(200).send({user: user.email , token: token}) 
    } else {
       res.status(400).send('password is wrong!');
    }

    
})


router.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
    let user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        passwordHash: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
        phone: req.body.phone,
        isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin,
        street: req.body.street,
        apartment: req.body.apartment,
        zip: req.body.zip,
        city: req.body.city,
        country: req.body.country,
    })
    user = await user.save();

    if(!user)
    return res.status(400).send('the user cannot be created!')

    res.send(user);
})


router.delete('/:id', (req, res)=>{
    User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).then(user =>{
        if(user) {
            return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'the user is deleted!'})
        } else {
            return res.status(404).json({success: false , message: "user not found!"})
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
       return res.status(500).json({success: false, error: err}) 
    })
})

router.get(`/get/count`, async (req, res) =>{
    const userCount = await User.countDocuments((count) => count)

    if(!userCount) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send({
        userCount: userCount
    });
})


module.exports =router;
```

This is my login.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import FormContainer from "../../Shared/Form/FormContainer";
import Input from "../../Shared/Form/Input";
import Error from "../../Shared/Error";
import EasyButton from "../../Shared/StyledComponents/EasyButton";

// Context
import AuthGlobal from "../../Context/store/AuthGlobal";
import { loginUser } from "../../Context/actions/Auth.actions";

const Login = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(AuthGlobal);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === true) {
      props.navigation.navigate("User Profile");
    }
  }, [context.stateUser.isAuthenticated]);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const user = {
      email,
      password,
    };

    if (email === "" || password === "") {
      setError("Please fill in your credentials");
    } else {
      loginUser(user, context.dispatch);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FormContainer title={"Login"}>
      <Input
        placeholder={"Enter Email"}
        name={"email"}
        id={"email"}
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text.toLowerCase())}
      />
      <Input
        placeholder={"Enter Password"}
        name={"password"}
        id={"password"}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
      />
      <View style={styles.buttonGroup}>
        {error ? <Error message={error} /> : null}
        <EasyButton large primary onPress={() => handleSubmit()}>
          <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Login</Text>
        </EasyButton>
      </View>
      <View style={[{ marginTop: 40 }, styles.buttonGroup]}>
        <Text style={styles.middleText}>Don't have an account yet?</Text>
        <EasyButton
        large
        secondary 
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Register")}>
          <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Register</Text>
        </EasyButton>
      </View>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonGroup: {
    width: "80%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  middleText: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
});

export default Login;
```

This is my user profile where user email, phone and orders is supposed to show.

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Container } from "native-base"
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native"
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage"
import OrderCard from "../../Shared/OrderCard"

import axios from "axios"
import baseURL from "../../assets/common/baseUrl"

import AuthGlobal from "../../Context/store/AuthGlobal"
import { logoutUser } from "../../Context/actions/Auth.actions"
import { useEffect } from 'react/cjs/react.development';

const UserProfile = (props) => {
    const context = useContext(AuthGlobal)
    const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState()
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState()

    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
        if (
            context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === false || 
            context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === null
        ) {
            props.navigation.navigate("Login")
        }

        AsyncStorage.getItem("jwt")
            .then((res) => {
                axios
                    .get(`${baseURL}users/${context.stateUser.user.sub}`, {
                        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${res}` },
                    })
                    .then((user) => setUserProfile(user.data))
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))

        axios
        .get(`${baseURL}orders`)
        .then((x) => {
            const data = x.data;
            console.log(data)
            const userOrders = data.filter(
                (order) => order.user._id === context.stateUser.user.sub
            );
            setOrders(userOrders);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))

        return () => {
            setUserProfile();
            setOrders();
        }

    }, [context.stateUser.isAuthenticated]))

    return (
       <Container style={styles.container}>
           <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.subContainer}>
               <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>
                   {userProfile ? userProfile.name : "" }
               </Text>
               <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                        Email: {userProfile ? userProfile.email : ""}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                        Phone: {userProfile ? userProfile.phone : ""}
                    </Text>
               </View>
               <View style={{ marginTop: 80 }}>
                    <Button title={"Sign Out"} onPress={() => [
                        AsyncStorage.removeItem("jwt"),
                        logoutUser(context.dispatch)
                    ]}/>
               </View>
               <View style={styles.order}>
                   <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>My Orders</Text>
                   <View>
                       {orders ? (
                           orders.map((x) => {
                               return <OrderCard key={x.id} {...x} />;
                           })
                       ) : (
                           <View style={styles.order}>
                               <Text>You have no orders</Text>
                           </View>
                       )}
                   </View>
               </View>
           </ScrollView>
       </Container>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    subContainer: {
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: 60
    },
    order: {
        marginTop: 20,
        alignItems: "center",
        marginBottom: 60
    }
})

export default UserProfile;
```

This is my auth.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer, userEffect, useState } from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage"

import authReducer from "../reducers/Auth.reducer";
import { setCurrentUser } from "../actions/Auth.actions";
import AuthGlobal from './AuthGlobal'

const Auth = props => {
    const [stateUser, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
        isAuthenticated: null,
        user: {}
    });
    const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setShowChild(true);
        if (AsyncStorage.jwt) {
            const decoded = AsyncStorage.jwt ? AsyncStorage.jwt : "";
            if (setShowChild) {
                dispatch(setCurrentUserUser(jwt_decode(decoded)))
            }
        }
        return () => setShowChild(false);
    }, [])


    if (!showChild) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (
            <AuthGlobal.Provider
                value={{
                    stateUser,
                    dispatch
                }}
            >
                {props.children}
            </AuthGlobal.Provider>
        )
    }
};

export default Auth;
```

Let me know if you need any more codes.
Thank-you for your valuable time.

Comment: You pass invalid ObjectId to findById mongoose method. Check the solution in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940660/whats-mongoose-error-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-xxx-at-path-id. Before search in the DB for the ID passed in req.params, check that  the ID is valid and not undefined or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In your API file

Import ObjectID from mongodb package

```
const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
```

And change findById like below :

```
const user = await User.findById({id:req.params.id}).select('-passwordHash');
```

or may be like this :

```
const user = await User.findById({id:ObjectID(req.params.id)}).select('-passwordHash');
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters. 
I get this error now.

Comment: can you `console.log(req.params.id)`

Comment: Whenever i log in, it says
GET /api/v1/users/undefined 401 40 - 1.544 ms
 in the terminal

Comment: Can I give you my zip file and take a look at it. Ive been stuck at it for days.

Comment: I've modified my answer, check the changes

Comment: Nothing changed, but now it says GET /api/v1//undefined 401 40 - 3.934 ms

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X-lD5_c7NhujvmFzfzxFJgWdF4K_yVwp/view

Can you take a look at this please. It would help a lot.

Comment: The email is abc@gmail.com and password is abcd
For Admin: leoanranjit@gmail.com Password: abcd

Comment: I found something, check the answer. Feel free to ask !

Comment: can you `console.log(req.params.id)` in your backend ,
It seems like problem is from react code

Comment: I think `context.stateUser.user.sub` didn't stored any value or id,
Could you please console that too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231504/discussion-between-dhaval-darji-and-ares).

Comment: I solved it :) the problem was just a typo in ._id

Comment: @ARES That's great can you please vote up my answer, That will help me too.