# OR operator with query builder in mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, mongoose

How do I do an 'OR' operator with query builder in Mongoose?

I tried something like this: Find a user by ID or Username
but it didn't work.

```
User.findOne({})
      .where( '_id', 'username').equals(param)
```

Comment: where is the or in that? can you write pseudocode of what you want to achieve? which version of Mongoose do you use?

Comment: Well, @boroboris that is my question... how to do an OR in mongoose, I am using latest version of Mongoose

Comment: I wanted to ask about the specific or conditions you want to use.

Comment: Oh sorry, I tried to pass an options inside the WHERE in this format   '_id', 'username'

Comment: I've found the part of the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382207/mongooses-find-method-with-or-condition-does-not-work-properly
so you can check that out too

Answer (score 12):

Try something along those lines:

```
User.findOne({
     $or:[ 
       {'condition_1':param}, {'condition_2':param} 
     ]},
     function(err,docs){
       if(!err) res.send(docs);
     }
  });
```

Comment: try it without a where. haven't tested this solution though

Answer (score 0):

**My solution**

```
// Needed to user ObjectID comparison
const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb'); 

// Check if param is a valid ID otherwise is Username
let id_or_username = ObjectID.isValid(id) ? '_id' : 'username';

// Find post by ID or Username
Home
  .findOne({})
  .where(id_or_shortid).equals(id)
  .exec(callback)
```